# Yet Another Forum integration with Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, yaf, orchardcms-1.8

I'd like to add YAF to my Orchard site. The problem is, I don't want users to have to sign up to both the site and forums.

Does anyone have some advice on how I may go about integrating the two, or perhaps suggest another forum which is easier to integrate? (I've tried the OrchardCMS forum module - don't really like it)